# Visual Studio - Shortcut to Navigate to Solution Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2010, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a keyboard shortcut in Visual Studio (aside from <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> and selection) that would take me from inside a document directly into the solution explorer? I don't want to customize any shortcuts or change any default behavior.

Comment: See: www.visualstudioshortcuts.com/2012/  (Though 2010 version is not available, it is still very useful).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio: Shortcut to scroll solution explorer to current file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14937284/visual-studio-shortcut-to-scroll-solution-explorer-to-current-file)

Comment: @stepanian fair point on primacy if this is earlier. I just meant duplicate i.e. they are the same. I was just linking them up for those doing admin.

Comment: @stepanian also I answered on this question not that - as I saw the date was earlier. Thanks

Answer (score 270, accepted):

> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>

should shift focus to the Solution Explorer.

For visual studio 2012 use:

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> this selects your current document in the solution explorer.

Comment: Thanks! And I assume ctrl + alt + l and then select the file with an arrow to come back?

Comment: Yup, press `Enter` to select the file, or `Escape` to just jump back to the document window without selecting the file :)

Comment: It also seems like ctrl + tab brings you back to the initial document with it selected (saving you the enter key press). Every second counts!

Comment: Oh sorry, by `selected` I thought you meant actually opened. `Escape` will return to document, whilst keeping the selection, but it won't open the file. (Similar to ctrl + tab). `Enter` will actually open the file.

Comment: In VS 2015, you can select "View" from the toolbar menu to see all the direct shortcuts for shifting focus to different windows. The same tricks (Escape, Enter) work for all of these.

Answer (score 53):

When using VS 2012 with the **Visual C# 2005 keyboard mapping scheme**:

> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd>

I find this easier to memorize: All shortcuts beginning with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> are for opening or navigating to **W** indows:

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd>: **S** olution Explorer
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>E</kbd>: **E** rror list
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>R</kbd>: **R** esourceview
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>A</kbd>: Command window (**A** ction ...)
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>T</kbd>: **T** askview
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>Q</kbd>: Find Symbol Results
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>X</kbd>: Toolbo **x**
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>C</kbd>: **C** lassview
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>P</kbd>: **P** roperties
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>B</kbd>: **B** ookmarks
- ...

Comment: Thank you for precising the keyboard mapping scheme ! I've been looking for using the shortcut Ctrl+W+S for the solution explorer since i installed a new VS2012 !

Answer (score 23):

In Visual Studio 2012 you can now use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> as this is the default keyboard shortcut for the solution explorer search box.

Comment: `Ctr+'` opens team explorer. `Ctrl + ,` opens "file selector".. Pretty handy shortcuts.

Answer (score 14):

On my windows 7 machine : <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> locks the computer.

For me 
: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>
works. (This could also be a resharper configuration)

Comment: Yes, Shift + Alt + L is resharper

Answer (score 13):

1. shortcut <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>[</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd> will focus current open file/document in solution explorer.
2. setting checkbox to true in "Track active in Solution Explorer" will automatically focus current open file/document in solution explorer (Tools->Options->Projects and solutions->General->"Track Active Item in Solution Explorer"=true

Answer (score 12):

The default keyboard shortcut for opening/jumping to Solution Explorer is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>.

Answer (score 11):

Extended above : command name for sync tab with solution explorer is "**SolutionExplorer.SyncWithActiveDocument**"

Comment: what monsters. How completely undiscoverable is that? You saved me ages <3.

Answer (score 8):

### Visual Studio

**2015** and **2017** (by **default**) [VS 2017 Shortcuts](http://visualstudioshortcuts.com/2017/)

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd>

Runs *Keyboard Shortcut*

```
SolutionExplorer.SyncWithActiveDocument
```

### ReSharper

In Visual Studio **2015** and **2017** (by **default**) [Resharper Docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Navigation_and_Search__Locating_a_File_in_Solution_Explorer.html)

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

Which runs *Resharper's Keyboard Shortcut*

```
Resharper.Resharper_LocateInSolutionOrAssemblyExplorer
```

### Both

- Focus Solution Explorer
- Highlight document
- Scroll / expand nodes (as required to show that document)

### Difference

**Resharper's** version also **works with decompiled code**. Locating decompiled symbols in the *Assembly Explorer* window.

To customise / it doesn't work :

1. Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard
2. Search shortcut name (e.g. SolutionExplorer.SyncWithActiveDocument)
3. Assign (in TextEditor) to Keyboard shortcuts as you like

(N.B. I used to use Global, but VS2022 + Resharper seemed to only accept either binding if was set in **TextEditor** not Global)

Comment: This. Re-assigning VS hotkey to "Text Editor" scope did the job. I use VS2022 and R#, got `Ctrl + [,S` suddenly broken after updating R# to a new _minor_ version. It was still assigned correctly in Keyboard shortcuts for "Global" scope. So I spent a lot of time on re-installing everything to just figure out that R# silently messed with one of hotkeys I use the most.

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>.

This shortcut will highlight the currently opened document in solution explorer.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem on a new machine build with VS 2013 and R# 8.2.

Keyboard option `Resharper.Resharper_LocateInSolutionExplorer` was correctly set to `Shift+Alt+L`, but it seemed to be only opening a parent folder and not selecting the actual file. As recommended in another post I enabled `"Track active in Solution Explorer"` in the VS Options.

This didn't fix the problem and wasn't what I want because in very large solutions I don't want the solution explorer jumping around to the current file in use. I disabled the Track feature and restarted VS, the `LocateInSolutionExplorer` feature then started working correctly. Some sort of shortcut precedence issue?

Answer (score 2):

For **AZERTY** keyboards like mine, the default shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>)</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> works fine even in VS 2019.

But if you have reassigned the above key to some other command (by mistake in my case) then the name of the command is `View.SolutionExplorer`

You can search it in the `Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard`
or just do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> and search `keymap`.

And then search `View.SolutionExplorer` in the `Show commands containing:` and assign whichever key you want.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We just upgraded from VS2013 to VS2017, and I had to go looking for how to auto-select the active tab in the Solution Explorer.  I often have to look for a document by finding a text-string from a screen, and love to have it select the document so I can see where it is.

Tracking the active document has been default behavior for a long time.  VS2017 brought over ALL my other preferences, but not this one.  Glad I found this thread--Thank you.