# Visual Studio: Shortcut to scroll solution explorer to current file

Tags: visual-studio

I'm **not asking** for the option to **automatically** follow the current file in the solution explorer. This has been answered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12682656/540352) and I have this option turned off because I hate the behavior.

I would like to have a shortcut (or macro, or ....) to jump to the file I'm currently editing in the solution explorer.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/a/55025095/661584 ?

Answer (score 123, accepted):

In VS 2013 there is a **built-in keyboard shortcut** (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd>)

1. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+backslash
2. Release both keys
3. Press the <kbd>S</kbd> key

Or click the button highlighted in the image bellow.

[image: Sync with active document]

One also has the option to [customize the keyboard shortcut](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5zwses53.aspx#bkmk_assign) if you don't like the default combination :)

Comment: This keyboard shortcut is called `SolutionExplorer.SyncWithActiveDocument` (Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard)

Comment: The default shortcut is Ctrl+[,S in my VS.

Comment: CTRL+backslash did not work for me actually, see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37158527/2874896

Comment: You may want to deactivate the `Track Active Item in Solution Explorer` first, so syncing solution explorer will only happen on pressing this shortcut instead of "jumping" around when switiching code files.

Answer (score 95):

In Visual Studio 2015, 2017, 2019 and 2022 you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd> and then <kbd>s</kbd>.

This will highlight the file currently being edited in Solution Explorer.

This can be configured via the following keyboard command: *SolutionExplorer.SyncWithActiveDocument*

To reconfigure, navigate to Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard

Comment: In Visual Studio 2015, with ReSharper, I am able to press "Shift" + "Alt" + "L" to highlight the current file being edited in Solution Explorer.

Comment: In Visual Studio 2013 update 5 this is also the correct combination.

Comment: @JeremyPaskali Thank you very much for this. As Im using resharper thats the easier way for me to go :).

Comment: Works also in 2017RC.

Comment: @JeremyPaskali - Can you add your comment as an answer?  I'm also using ReSharper, and this key combo was the only one that worked for me.

Comment: @PhilipPittle, I've added my comment as an answer now.  Thanks for asking me to do this.

Comment: @C4u, I've added my comment as an answer now.

Comment: For those that are wanting to remap the shortcut to something else, in 2019 the command is called "SolutionExplorer.SyncWithActiveDocument".

Comment: Ctrl-), s for people that are using Azerty

Answer (score 29):

As far as I know there is no such option before VS 2012.

In VS 2012 the "Sync with Active Document" option was introduced. You can find description and screen on [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2012/06/21/visual-studio-2012-new-features-solution-explorer.aspx) (scroll to "Sync with Active Document" in the middle of page).

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer as it precisely answers the question.

Comment: We're using Resharper now. It has a feature to do exactly this. Default shortcut: Shift+Alt+L

Comment: Thanks for the Resharper command, I was searching for that as well.

Comment: This is definitely the answer and does not require 3rd party tools like ReSharper. 

Ctrl + ' [ ' then 's'
Or: Press 'Ctrl' and Left Square Bracket, then 's'

Answer (score 6):

To locate the file you're currently editing in Solution Explorer:

***`Ctrl + W + S`***

I previously used `Shift + Alt + L`, but for some reason this is no longer working.

The other suggestions (*`Ctrl+\,S`* and *`Ctrl+[,S`* and Ctrl + ` + S) do not work for me in VS2015. I don't use resharper and dont like using macros when simple shortcuts are available.

Comment: This is the only that worked for me in VS 2017, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

In Visual Studio 2015, with ReSharper, I am able to press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> to highlight the current file being edited in Solution Explorer.

Comment: I'm also using ReSharper and this was the only keyboard combination that worked for me.  Maybe ReSharper overrides the VS defaults?

Comment: Do you know the name of the keyboard command where this shortcut can be configured?

Answer (score 3):

For VS2010 I found this macro and works for me :

```
Imports System
Imports EnvDTE
Imports EnvDTE80
Imports EnvDTE90

Public Module Utilities
    Public Sub TrackProjectItem()
        Dim solution As Solution2 = DTE.Solution
        If Not solution.IsOpen OrElse DTE.ActiveDocument Is Nothing Then Return

        solution.FindProjectItem(DTE.ActiveDocument.FullName).ExpandView()

        Dim FileName As String = DTE.ActiveDocument.FullName

        Dim SolutionExplorerPath As String
        Dim items As EnvDTE.UIHierarchyItems = DTE.ToolWindows.SolutionExplorer.UIHierarchyItems
        Dim item As Object = FindItem(items, FileName, SolutionExplorerPath)

        If item Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox("Couldn't find the item in Solution Explorer.")
            Return
        End If

        DTE.Windows.Item(Constants.vsWindowKindSolutionExplorer).Activate()
        DTE.ActiveWindow.Object.GetItem(SolutionExplorerPath).Select(vsUISelectionType.vsUISelectionTypeSelect)
    End Sub

    Public Function FindItem(ByVal Children As UIHierarchyItems, ByVal FileName As String, ByRef SolutionExplorerPath As String) As Object
        For Each CurrentItem As UIHierarchyItem In Children
            Dim TypeName As String = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Information.TypeName(CurrentItem.Object)
            If TypeName = "ProjectItem" Then
                Dim projectitem As EnvDTE.ProjectItem = CType(CurrentItem.Object, EnvDTE.ProjectItem)
                Dim i As Integer = 1
                While i <= projectitem.FileCount
                    If projectitem.FileNames(i) = FileName Then
                        SolutionExplorerPath = CurrentItem.Name
                        Return CurrentItem
                    End If
                    i = i + 1
                End While
            End If

            Dim ChildItem As UIHierarchyItem = FindItem(CurrentItem.UIHierarchyItems, FileName, SolutionExplorerPath)
            If Not ChildItem Is Nothing Then
                SolutionExplorerPath = CurrentItem.Name + "\" + SolutionExplorerPath
                Return ChildItem
            End If
        Next
    End Function
End Module
```

Original Source [here](http://dvanderboom.wordpress.com/2008/03/21/visual-studio-macro-track-item-in-solution-explorer-on-demand/)

Answer (score 3):

In Visual Studio 2010/2012 you can use this extension ([link](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d491911d-97f3-4cf6-87b0-6a2882120acf)).
It adds option to sync on Solution Explorer toolbar and code context menu.

Comment: the "link" open this same page XD

Comment: It shows a new menu item "Find In Solution Explorer" to the context menu when you right click on our document tab. this menu is positioned between the "Copy Full Path" and "Open Containing Folder" menu items.

Answer (score 3):

For VS 2017 the default configuration is:

> CTRL + [,S

And the complete list of shortcuts you can find here:

http://visualstudioshortcuts.com/2017/

Answer (score 1):

If I got your question right, you can go to Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> General and check the "Track Active Item in Solution Explorer" option.

Comment: You're a saint. Works for me in VS 2019.
Granted, not what the OP asked, but very useful to have on here anyway.

Comment: No, the question explicitly asks not for this.

Answer (score 0):

On my keyboard I had to press:

**Ctrl** + **`**  + **S**

Do note that the sign in the middle is the key just left of the backspace.

Using Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: It might help if you said which layout you‘re using. The info where the key is located is helpful though.

Answer (score -1):

On Visual Studio the **Sync With Active Document** icon [image: Sync with Active Document icon VS2019] is not displayed when the **"Track Active Item in Solution Explorer"** option is already ticked under ***Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > General***.

To display the icon  and perform the sync manually untick the **"Track Active Item in Solution Explorer"** option

[image: Track Active Item in Solution Explorer unticked]

or use the keyboard shortcut: **"Ctrl"** and **"["** and **"s"** together on the active page

In Visual Studio 2013 the icon appears differently. It appears as a right and left pointer icon [image: Sync With Active Document VS2013].

On Visual Studio 2019 the refresh icon with circular double arrows is now the Sync button [image: Sync with Active Document icon VS2019]

Comment: The question explicitly asks not for this.