# 'Sync with Active Document' button not working for some files

Tags: visual-studio, projects-and-solutions

I use Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 and it looks like this button is working in one project (WPF app.) and not working in other project (server app.) within the same solution. Which VS setting did I possibly have broken?

Answer (score 22):

"Sync with Active Document" stopped working for me in VS 2015, both the button on top of Solution Explorer, as well as the Shortcut (Ctl + [, S).

I fixed this by first turning on the automatic sync, and then turning if back off. (This is done in Tools | Options | Projects and Solutions | General, with "Track Active Item in Solution Explorer")

Comment: Did not fix the issue in VS 2019 I have for some files.

Comment: Ha, did you try turning it off and on again.

Comment: Upvoted because you mentioned how this is configured in Tools | Options...

Comment: Note: If you have Resharper installed it will most likely silently turn the options off. You will have to disable the silent performance fix first. Then turn it on and off.

Answer (score 18):

Enable at:

```
Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > General > Track Active Item in Solution Explorer
```

Works with VS 2017.

Comment: This works for VS 2019 as well. I am using enterprise version

Comment: The question asks about using the button to get from the open file to the solution explorer, not the always-on 'track active item' option.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it by setting up the shortcut to "Text Editor" instead of letting it as a "Global" shortcut.

Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard

[image: Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard]

Comment: This worked for me. I was struggling after installing Resharper on VS2022 and this solved it. More info https://stackoverflow.com/a/55025095/661584